# How can I check if a column in a dataframe is a factor without using apply?

Tags: r

I currently have a function that uses sapply to check whether a column is a data frame, and it's giving me problems when I call it in another function. Long story short, I just want to see if there is another way to do this.

```
   if (sapply(df[,col],is.factor)) {
```

this is what I'm currently using, but I want to eliminate the use of apply.

Comment: If you know the name of the column, why not `is.factor(df$col)`?

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a hack.**

I cannot tell if it works in the question's case, since there is no data set example. I will use built-in data set `iris`.

```
col <- "Species"

s <- capture.output(str(iris))
grepl("Factor", s[grep(col, s)])
#[1] TRUE
```

**As a function (not vectorized):**

```
checkFactorCol <- function(x, col){
  s <- capture.output(str(x))
  grepl("Factor", s[grep(col, s)])
}

checkFactorCol(iris, "Sepal.Length")  # FALSE
checkFactorCol(iris, "Species")       # TRUE
```

**Vectorized:**

```
checkFactorCol <- Vectorize(checkFactorCol, "col")

checkFactorCol(iris, names(iris))
#Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#       FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE         TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use it inside a if, why don't you apply the is.factor function directly to the column?

```
if(is.factor(df[,col])){
   ....
}
```